# Perché non si dice 'in Lazio' ma 'nel Lazio'?

Tags: word-usage, articles, prepositions

Perché si dice 'Latina è nel Lazio', ma, p.e., 'Genova è in Liguria', 'Palermo è in Sicilia' e così via?

Comment: related: http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utente:PersOnLine/uso_dell%27articolo#Toponimi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non è l'unica regione che “fa eccezione”: anche *nel Veneto* è molto usato come si evince da [questo NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nel%20Veneto,in%20Veneto&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,nel%20Veneto;,c0;.t1;,in%20Veneto;,c0)

[image]

Naturalmente il risultato è da prendere con molta cautela, perché, per esempio, *nel Veneto di oggi* non può essere *in Veneto di oggi*; in ogni caso la risalita di *in Veneto* sembra essere piuttosto recente.

Sull'articolo con i nomi geografici è difficile dare regole precise. Non c'è dubbio che i nomi plurali vogliono l'articolo (*nelle Marche* o l'antiquato *nelle Puglie*), quelli singolari possono variare.

Comment: Si noti anche "nelle Marche", che essendo plurale è magari ovvio.

Comment: In Veneto si riferisce al dialetto veneto. Nel veneto alla regione. Quindi l'Ngram é interessante ma mostra una tendenza diversa da quella voluta