# "In Belgio" oppure "nel Belgio"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

La mia domanda è riguardo a frasi come, per esempio:

> *Ho viaggiato **in** Belgio.*
>
> *Ho viaggiato **nel** Belgio.*
>
> *Sono andata **in** Belgio.*
>
> *Sono andata **nel** Belgio.*
>
> *Sono stata **in** Belgio.*
>
> *Sono stata **nel** Belgio.*
>
> *Sono arrivata **in** Belgio.*
>
> *Sono arrivata **nel** Belgio.*

Qual è la forma considerata più corretta: "in Belgio" oppure "nel Belgio"?

Comment: Normalmente varrebbe la risposta di Kokoroatari: "in"+"articolo"+"paese con unica parola al singolare" solo se ne specifichi una qualità. La domanda però riguarda specificamente il Belgio, e qui le regole possono essere diverse. Per il Belgio si possono usare entrambe le forme, sia "in Belgio" che "nel Belgio", ma con sottili, spesso impercettibili, sfumature di significato. Per esempio "ho viaggiato nel Belgio" significa che hai visitato il Belgio, hai viaggiato **per il** Belgio; "ho viaggiato in Belgio" stona, hai fatto un viaggio per andare in Belgio o hai viaggiato mentre stavi in Belgio?

Comment: L'ambiguità di cui su deriva dal fatto che il verbo italiano [viaggiare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/viaggiare/) non vuole il complemento di moto a luogo, non puoi dire "ho viaggiato in Italia" per dire che hai fatto un viaggio per andare in Italia. Quindi forse varrebbe la pena separare le due questioni e scegliere un diverso esempio (andar mi faccia il Re nel … Belgio?).

Comment: Non capisco molto bene cosa vuoi dire. Ho letto molte volte: "viaggiare in Italia", "viaggiare in Europa", eccetera. Il tuo esempio dell'opera ***Don Carlo*** significa che dovrei porre la domanda usando altri verbi come "andare", "stare", "arrivare", eccetera? Bene, cerco di farlo.

Comment: Puoi dire "viaggiare in Italia", ma non significa che vai in Italia bensì che viaggi **per** l'Italia o mentre stai in Italia (a seconda dei contesti). Che io sappia non esistono casi per cui il verbo "viaggiare" regga il complemento di **moto a luogo**. Per quanto riguarda il Belgio, questo fa eccezione alla regola suggerita da Kokoroatari e vuole l'articolo in molti casi in cui altri paesi non lo vorrebbero. Si pensi ad asempio al "Re del Belgio", che non si dice "Re di Belgio" (laddove invece si diceva "Re d'Italia", non "Re dell'Italia").

Comment: La mia impressione è che, almeno fino a qualche decennio fa, l'articolo fosse molto comune davanti a nomi di nazione (o di regione) maschili: *nel Belgio*, *nel Congo*, *nel Veneto*. Ormai, però, l'uso sembra uniformato a quello con i nomi femminili. Fanno ovviamente caso a sé i nomi plurali che vogliono senz'altro l'articolo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La mia impressione è che, almeno in passato, l'articolo fosse molto comune nel caso di nazioni o regioni di genere maschile: *nel Belgio*, *nel Veneto*, *nel Lazio* (si veda [Perché non si dice 'in Lazio' ma 'nel Lazio'?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/)).

[Questo Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nel%20Belgio%2Cin%20Belgio&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnel%20Belgio%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20Belgio%3B%2Cc0) mostra il cambiamento di tendenza intorno alla metà del ventesimo secolo. L'analogo Ngram per “nel Congo,in Congo” mostra che la prima forma ha il sopravvento anche fino a più tardi. Per “nel Giappone,in Giappone” l'inversione di tendenza è precedente.

Come sempre, i risultati degli Ngram vanno presi con le pinze, ma comunque sembrano suffragare l'impressione che la “regola” fosse

- articolo con i nomi maschili (*nel Belgio*),
- niente articolo con i nomi femminili (*in Olanda*),
- sempre l'articolo con i nomi plurali (*nelle Fiandre*, *negli Stati Uniti*).

Per i nomi singolari, però, sembra ormai prevalere l'uniformità, cioè senza articolo.

Comment: Sospetto che originariamente "Belgio", "Veneto", "Lazio" indicassero zone ben determinate in qualche senso di cui poi storicamente si è persa la memoria, e quindi richiedessero - o suggerissero - l'uso dell'articolo determinativo (ma non ho nessuna fonte a riguardo). Nota che molti Stati dal nome maschile - forse la maggior parte - non vogliono l'articolo (vado in Brasile, in Pakistan, in Bangladesh, in Giappone, in Messico, in Vietnam, in Egitto, in Iran, in Kenya, in Sudan, in Uganda, in Canada, in Iraq, in Afghanistan, in Venezuela, in Perù, etc.). Invece Dante diceva "nel Morrocco" …

Comment: Sono sicuro di aver sentito *nel Canadà*, *nel Pakistan* e *nel Vietnam* o *del Vietnam*: è *guerra del Vietnam* e mai senza articolo come *guerra di Crimea*.

Answer (score 6):

In linea di principio puoi pensare di aggiungere l'articolo (ne+il = nel) quando specifichi una qualità del paese.

- In Italia è difficile trovare lavoro
- Nell'Italia *di oggi* è difficile trovare lavoro

Senza una specificazione a seguire suona sbagliata:

- Nell'Italia è difficile trovare lavoro (x)

Altri esempi:

- Ho viaggiato in Belgio
- Con la mia macchina del tempo ho viaggiato nel Belgio del secolo scorso
- Grazie al suo racconto ho rivisto il Belgio della mia infanzia/dei miei ricordi

Answer (score 0):

La forma più corretta e comunemente utilizzata è

> Ho viaggiato **in** Belgio

**"In"** è una preposizione semplice ed esprime un complemento di luogo, serve a rispondere alla domanda **"Dove?"**.

**"Nel"** è una preposizione articolata, composta dalla preposizione **"In"** e dall'articolo **"Il"**.

Comment: Non ho capito il tuo ragionamento. Si dice comunemente “il Belgio”, quindi che cosa in quello che dici dovrebbe escludere l'uso di “nel Belgio”?

Comment: In breve e a orecchio. Aggiungere l'articolo (ne+il) dà l'impressione che sia inteso come tutto, nel suo complesso, come se io avessi viaggiato per tutto il Belgio, in lungo e in largo. "*In* Belgio" suona come "all'interno del Belgio".
Ovviamente non vale per tutte le preposizioni (non dico "Ho viaggiato per Italia"). Per esempio se hai "per", "con" o nessuna preposizione, non puoi prescindere dall'uso dell'articolo, mentre se hai "in", o anche "di" o "tra", puoi... per motivi diversi da caso a caso. A volte simili però:
Fratelli d'Italia (l'Italia nel complesso)/
Fratelli dell'Italia che fu

Comment: Il mio commento va letto dopo la mia risposta o non penso sia chiaro... sowwy^^;;

Answer (score 0):

È corretto usare 'in', ma, sebbene non per il Belgio - almeno nei casi proposti -, pure 'nel' può essere usato, eventualmente anche per esprimere il medesimo significato, né aprioristicamente è possibile escludere l'uso indifferente di 'nel' e 'il'.