# "D'Australia" oppure "dell'Australia"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, prepositions, articles

Come si deve dire: " d'Australia" oppure "dell'Australia"? Per esempio, quale tra queste due sarebbe la forma corretta?

> - "Una cittadina d'Australia"
> - "Una cittadina dell'Australia"

Ho avuto questo dubbio perché so che si dice "le regioni d'Italia", "le città d'Italia", "il giro d'Italia", "la banca d'Italia"... e non capisco perché dovrebbe essere diverso per altri paesi.

Si potrebbe fare la stessa domanda con il nome di un altro paese: si deve usare la preposizione "di" semplice o la preposizione articolata?

Comment: @Josh61: Ma si dice, per esempio, "città d'Italia" e non "città dell'Italia", no?

Comment: Città d'Italia suona molto da Guida del Touring Club. Città italiane sarebbe un'espressione più comune. Cittadina ***di Australia*** è sbagliato, comunque.

Comment: Ma anche "le regioni d'Italia", "il giro d'Italia", "la banca d'Italia"... Non capisco bene la differenza con "Australia".

Comment: Penso che  ***d'Italia*** sia un espressione arcaica rimasta nel linguaggio contemporaneo, (Fratelli d'Italia). Domanda interessante !!

Comment: Non è un po' simile a [questa domanda](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2055/in-belgio-oppure-nel-belgio)? Comunque l'oscillazione tra la presenza e l'assenza degli articoli con i nomi di nazioni dipende dalla nazione, dall'uso, da frasi fatte... Per esempio, diremmo “la capitale (il presidente, il PIL...) della Francia”, ma non suona troppo strano, e al massimo un po' desueto, “il re di Francia”. E così via.

Comment: Credo vadano imparati i singoli casi

Comment: @gd1: Ed è "dell'Australia", ma "d'Italia"?

Comment: In questo caso sì, ma poi trovi `il PIL dell'Italia` (e non `d'Italia`) la capitale che può essere tanto `d'Italia` quanto `dell'Italia`, ecc... Tale Amadeo Giannini secondo quanto riportato da Wikipedia fondò la "la Banca d'America e d'Italia" e "dell'America" in effetti suonerebbe male, ma "Reserve Bank of Australia" si traduce serenamente con "Banca nazionale dell'Australia". Esattamente come ha detto DaG la questione è multidimensionale... c'è intanto la nazione e il "cosa", ma poi chissà quali altre dimensioni. Andrei caso per caso.

Comment: Se poi andiamo in Australia oppure nel Mozambico, la faccenda si complica. `;-)` C'entra molto l'eufonia, almeno per la proposizione *in*.

Comment: I re sono quasi tutti “di”, ma il re del Belgio fa eccezione.

Comment: @gd1: Se le cose stanno così, dato che i casi diversi immagino siano innumerevoli, penso che una buona risposta alla domanda possa consistere in alcuni esempi.

Comment: Si potrebbe fare, ma trovo sia una strategia più pragmatica fare intanto una raccolta dei commenti che hai ricevuto e poi risolvere ogni caso quando te lo trovi davanti. Il rischio altrimenti è che provi a creare una tassonomia dove non credo ci sia. Ora ho notato che hai fatto anche questa domanda: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5533/nellunione-sovietica-oppure-in-unione-sovietica?rq=1 Credo sia ora di accettare e "abbracciare" il caos, purtroppo

Comment: Comunque usando le preposizioni articolate non ti sbagli mai; se sei in dubbio usa quelle, poi man mano ti impari i casi in cui si può usare "di" o "d'".

Answer (score 4):

Mentre si dice normalmente *una città d'Italia*, suonerebbe davvero bizzarro *una città di Germania*. A orecchio, *città di Francia* o *di Spagna* mi suonerebbero forse affettate, ma non “sbagliate”; con altre nazioni andrei direttamente per la preposizione articolata, con molte eccezioni (vedi più avanti il riferimento a Nicosia).

Altri casi: *la regina Elisabetta d'Inghilterra* va bene, ma si deve dire *il re Filippo del Belgio* (sebbene dovrebbe essere, più propriamente, *il re Filippo dei Belgi*). Tuttavia, Oxford è una città *dell'Inghilterra*, come Anversa è una città *del Belgio*. Alla domanda *dov'è Oxford/Anversa?* risponderei però *in Inghilterra* e *in Belgio*. Al contrario, Maputo è una città *del Mozambico* e si trova *nel Mozambico* (ma forse anche *in Mozambico*); Nicosia è una città *di Cipro* e si trova *a Cipro* o *nell'isola di Cipro*.

Dubito che si possa stabilire una regola d'uso della preposizione articolata con i nomi geografici senza dover aggiungere una caterva di eccezioni. Vedi, per esempio, [Usage of prepositions "a" and "in" in statements about places and directions](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/usage-of-prepositions-a-and-in-in-statements-about-places-and-directions/1212?s=1|0.0457#1212)

La preposizione *di* ha gli stessi problemi. Sebbene si dica *in Egitto*, la locuzione *città d'Egitto* verrebbe forse intesa come parte del [noto modo di dire](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/egitto/). Ma il nome della seconda città di quella nazione è, naturalmente, *Alessandria d'Egitto*.

Altri esempi: [*Reggio di Calabria*](http://www.reggiocal.it/on-line/Home.html) e *Reggio nell'Emilia* sono i nomi ufficiali di due capoluoghi di provincia italiani (ma il [sito istituzionale](http://www.municipio.re.it/retecivica/urp/pes.nsf/web/Hmttl?opendocument) del secondo ha *Reggio Emilia*).

Riassumendo: non c'è una regola. Questo tipo di problemi va risolto caso per caso, magari tenendo conto dell'eufonia: *in Liechtenstein* suona meno bene di *nel Liechtenstein*, almeno secondo le regole eufoniche del toscano che rifiuta certe combinazioni di consonanti.

Comment: Come dire, ci vuole orecchio!!  Forse per questo gli stranieri sbagliano spesso le preposizioni, in effetti non essendoci una regola come in questo caso (e stiamo parlando di espressioni molto comuni) l'uso  è l'unico riferimento valido.

Comment: @Josh61 Sì, certo: *di Germania* è uno dei tipici modi per imitare uno straniero che si sforza di parlare in italiano.

Answer (score 2):

Cerco di fare qui una raccolta di quello che è stato detto nei commenti. Vi invito ad aggiungere altri casi.

Come affermato da @gd1, per sapere se usare la preposizione "di" semplice o la preposizione articolata prima del nome di un paese, si devono imparare i singoli casi separatamente. In parole di @DaG, l'oscillazione tra la presenza e l'assenza degli articoli con i nomi di nazioni dipende dalla nazione, dall'uso, da frasi fatte...

L'esempio della domanda è

> - Una città/cittadina dell'Australia.

Altri esempi che sono stati menzionati nella discussione sono:

> - Città/cittadina d'Italia.
> - Regione d'Italia.
> - Il Giro d'Italia, il Derby d'Italia, la Banca d'Italia.
> - Il PIL dell'Italia.
> - La capitale può essere tanto "d'Italia" quanto "dell'Italia".
> - La capitale, il presidente, il PIL... della Francia.
> - Con i re si usa quasi sempre "di", come "il re di Francia", ma "il re del Belgio" fa eccezione.
> - Secondo quanto riportato da Wikipedia, un tale Amadeo Giannini fondò la "la Banca d'America e d'Italia", ma "Reserve Bank of Australia" si traduce con "Banca nazionale dell'Australia".

Comment: Pignoleria: non direi che “re del Belgio” sia una specifica eccezione, bensì che anche per i re ci siano usi fossilizzati (“d'Inghilterra” ma “del Belgio”) e che semmai, per un re menzionato di rado, venga più spontaneo usare la preposizione articolata (io direi “il re dello Swaziland”, per esempio).

Comment: Perché non la fai community wiki questa? Così tutti potrebbero editarci dentro i casi che gli vengono in mente.

Comment: @kos: Buona idea, lo faccio adesso!