# Non abbiamo... "tutta la notte" vs "la tutta notte" vs "la notte tutta"?

Tags: grammar, word-order

Sorry for asking a probably trivial question, but I am so far merely a happy amateur at Italian.

Which of the following is most correct or sounds most natural in italian?

1. tutta la notte
2. la tutta notte
3. la notte tutta

In the context "we don't have all night (to do something)". Non abbiamo ... ?

Comment: Not trivial at all, because the adjective *tutto* is quite peculiar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The adjective *tutto* has a rather peculiar role in the Italian language in that it usually *precedes* the article relative to the modified noun.

From the Treccani dictionary

> **1. a.** Come agg., riferito a nomi singolari, ne indica l’intera estensione nello spazio o nel tempo, l’intera quantità, o esprime il concetto della pienezza, della compiutezza: *t. il mondo*, *t. la piazza*, *t. la casa*; *t. il mese*, *t. la settimana*; *non ha fatto che brontolare per t. la strada*; *sapeva t. la lezione*, *conosce t. Dante a memoria*; di cose non materiali: *sviluppare t. la propria potenza*; *metterci t. l’impegno*, ecc.; in funzione di predicato: *la roba, o la questione, è tutta qui*. **Come si vede dagli esempi, quando è usato in funzione attributiva è seguito, non preceduto, dall’articolo**; questo manca davanti a nomi proprî di persona (*t. Dante*) e anche di città, che comunem. rifiutino l’articolo (*tutta Roma*, *tutta Napoli*, ma *tutto il Cairo*, *tutta l’Aquila*, ecc.); in alcune espressioni l’articolo manca anche con nomi comuni: *con t. libertà*, *di t. cuore*, ecc.; *assumere una donna a t. servizio*, a pieno tempo o per svolgere mansioni molteplici; in altri usi l’assenza dell’articolo è eccezionale: *in t. Italia*; *s’è lamentato t. notte*; *t. giorno*, ant., sempre, continuamente (parziale calco del fr. *toujours*), diverso perciò da *t. il giorno* (v. anche tuttodì): *che si veggono e odono tutto giorno* (Leopardi).

The part I marked in boldface can be translated as

> As it can be seen from the examples, when it is used in attributive function it is followed, not preceded, by the article

The article is omitted when the sense is abstract (*in tutta libertà*, with full freedom) or figurative (*di tutto cuore*, with all the heart). I'd also add *in tutta fretta* (in a hurry, hastily).

The final examples are mostly antiquate except for *in tutta Italia* or *in tutta Europa* (but *in tutta la Francia* and *in tutta l'Asia*; only *Italia*, *Europa* and a few other insular nations don't want the article if preceded by *tutta*).

Thus *la tutta notte* cannot be used. On the other hand, an inversion such as *la notte tutta* could be used in poetry or to give a particular emphasis, but it should be rare. Note that, conversely, *intero* doesn't behave like *tutto* and one has to say *l'intera notte*.

Other adjectives don't behave this way. One could say *verde il prato*, but in rather specific contexts, for instance in oppositions: *ho visto un bel paesaggio: verde il prato, scuro il bosco e fresche le acque del torrente*, but it would show affectation.

Comment: Great, helpful answer. As for the names of countries, I'd say that the present one is only a particular case of the inconsistency of Italian about the use of articles with them (as you described [here](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5704/daustralia-oppure-dellaustralia)).  We say, for instance, _la capitale di Cipro_, so we also say _in tutta Cipro_.

Comment: @DaG Yes, I forgot about it; I added “a few other insular nations”, which seems correct. I'm not going to check the full list of nations. `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

First one, definitely.
The last one would seem more poetic.
The middle one sounds broken.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! This answer could be improved by adding references or explanations (why is the second one "broken"?)

Answer (score 3):

The first one is the correct one.

> Non abbiamo tutta la notte

The second is wrong and the last one is formally correct, even though it may sound weird.

If you are interested to go deeper about word order you may take a look to [this question](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order/1256#1256)