# Perché Israele non vuole l'articolo?

Tags: articles, proper-nouns

Per i nomi di nazioni e stati indipendenti, quando usati come soggetto*, si usa l'articolo determinativo (ad es. la Spagna, il Marocco).

Fanno eccezione molte isole (Cuba, Taiwan, Malta, Cipro) e città stato (Monaco, San Marino).

Mi pare che Israele sia l'unica eccezione a sé stante, non facente parte delle due classi dette. Come mai? Ed è l'origine di questa eccezionalità spiegata o ricercata su qualche fonte**?

---

<sup>(*) o in generale quando non preceduti da "in" o in altre espressioni particolari</sup>

<sup>(**) c'è chi avanza la proposta (per me convincente) che il motivo sia che Israele è nome proprio di persona, ma mi piacerebbe trovare una fonte metodologicamente solida per evitare di fare un processo simile alla pseudoetimologia</sup>

Comment: Ispirato da: https://twitter.com/giorgiogilestro/status/1435893763537309697

Comment: Intanto, se non l'avessi vista, segnalo [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5704/daustralia-oppure-dellaustralia/5706#5706) a una domanda analoga: non è un duplicato, perché non si parla di Israele e si parla soprattutto di nomi di nazioni in posizioni diverse dal soggetto, ma comunque ci sono spunti interessanti.

Comment: Poi, non c'è una spiegazione del perché, ma la grammatica italiana di Serianni conferma il fatto in sé: parlando di nomi di regioni, stati e continenti usati come soggetto o complemento oggetto, «l'articolo è di norma presente ... Tuttavia manca con _Israele_ e coi nomi di alcuni stati insulari: _Cuba_, _Haiti_, _Cipro_, _Formosa_», con un rinvio bibliografico a una grammatica di Luciano Satta.

Comment: Su due piedi mi viene il dubbio che sia stato influenzato dall'uso biblico (in cui *Israele* è nome proprio) ma non saprei dare una fonte precisa..

Comment: Nelle traduzioni in italiano della Bibbia, i due regni in cui il popolo ebreo si trovò diviso sono chiamati “Israele” e “Giuda”. Si veda il capitolo 15 del primo libro dei Re.

Comment: Azzardo un'ipotesi (ma si tratta di un'ipotesi campata per aria, senza alcuna pezza a supporto): è possibile che la cosa dipenda dal fatto che, a causa della diaspora, per millenni "*(il popolo di) Israele*" ha indicato una nazione, ma non un luogo fisico ben definito?

Comment: Forse dipende dal fatto che è uno stato molto recente, nato nell'ultimo secolo (a parte l'uso in contesti storici/religiosi). Anche Dubai non ha un articolo.

Comment: @Barbojo Ho convertito la risposta in commento: per una risposta del genere occorre qualcosa di più di un “forse”.

Comment: Oppure, quando Israele è stato creato, era fondamentalmente come una città-stato?

Comment: @Sabrina: Già qualcun altro ha proposta questa idea dello stato “nuovo”, ma ci sono varie decine di nazioni giovani quanto (il moderno stato di) Israele o più, cioè successive al 1948, e hanno tutte l'articolo, a parte isole e città: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_by_date_of_formation

Answer (score -1):

Israele è originariamente il nome di una specifica persona (Giacobbe) e direi che questo sia il motivo per cui è naturale chiamarlo senza articolo. A un italoparlante con un po' di frequentazione della Bibbia questo risulta piuttosto evidente, nelle Scritture tradotte in italiano Israele è sempre indicato senza articolo.

https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israele_(nome)

Anche Giuda, l'altro regno ebraico nel sud della Palestina, viene indicato senza articolo per la stessa ragione.

Comment: Era già stato proposto nei commenti, ma appunto come commento perché non era stata trovata una fonte in merito. Tu hai qualche fonte (sul nesso “in origine era un nome di persona, quindi anche come nome di nazione non regge l'articolo”)?

Comment: Scusate, mi ero perso qualche commento. La fonte sul fatto che Israele deriva da un nome di persona è il Vecchio Testamento, addirittura il primo libro (Genesi). Nella voce Wikipedia che ho linkato ci sono tutti i riferimenti. I nomi di persona in italiano non vogliono l'articolo.

Comment: Sì, che Israele sia un nome di persona è noto (non serve certo la Wikipedia); mi devo essere spiegato male. Il nesso mancante è, come scrivevo sopra: “in origine era un nome di persona, quindi anche come nome di nazione non regge l'articolo”. Questo dov'è scritto.

Comment: Ho capito cosa intendi: no, non ho trovato una fonte che faccia 2 + 2.

Comment: Noto solo adesso che l'OP stesso dice “c'è chi avanza la proposta (per me convincente) che il motivo sia che Israele è nome proprio di persona, ma mi piacerebbe trovare una fonte metodologicamente solida per evitare di fare un processo simile alla pseudoetimologia”.